# jquery scroll mouse wheel if input has hidden text with text-indent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" style="width: 50px" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus viverra ullamcorper tellus, in varius erat mollis in. Suspendisse condimentum turpis sit amet tortor bibendum cursus lobortis enim posuere." />
```

The text is longer than the input width and the only way to view this is it you select the text which is hidden.

Is there a way to detect the scroll of the mousewheel up/down and change the `text-indent`?

I dont want this to effect the ability to select the text, e.g I wanted to copy/paste a single word "Phasellus".

Also be good if this worked for touch screen devices.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4g8X/)

1. It needs to only text-indent the text if its hidden (longer than the input width+padding+border)
2. Make it impossible to scroll too many and the text get completely hidden.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want this to be a `<textarea>`?

Comment: I have 20+ inputs on the same page and think this would look really bad with all these different scroll bars. The `<input />` looks much cleaner.

Comment: You could hide the scrollbars with `overflow: hidden` styles for the text areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use jquery mousewheel event. you can use [this](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos) plugin to get up and down of mouse wheel

```
$("input").on('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
        var dir = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down',
            vel = Math.abs(delta);
        $(this).text(dir + ' at a velocity of ' + vel);
        return false;
 });
```

Comment: But what happens if the text is less for another input? Can we prevent this from scrolling "text-indent" the text off screen?

Comment: You can  compare scroll width input width before scroll